# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.Exception.What's the issue?It's crashing on every div class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc

It's crashing on my `CardDetailsView`, the Details `IActionResult` in my `CardsController`.

CardDetailsView:

```
public class CardDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SNumber { get; set; }
    public string QNumber { get; set; }
}
```

CardDetailsView:

```
@model CardDetailsViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details"; }

<h1 style="margin: 2%; text-align: center;">Card Details</h1>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="startPoint">Title</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="startPoint" name="StartPoint" value="@Model.Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="endPoint">Destination</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="endPoint" name="EndPoint" value="@Model.Destination">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="departureTime">Model</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="departureTime" value="@Model.Model">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="seats">SNumber</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="seats" name="Seats" value="@Model.SNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">QNumber</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="description" name="Description" value="@Model.QNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="button-holder">
                <a href="/Cards/Details?cardId=@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase">Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CardsController:

```
public class CardsController : Controller
{
    public readonly DigitalCardsDbContext data;

    public CardsController(DigitalCardsDbContext data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public IActionResult Add() => View();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(CardAddViewModel card)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(card);
        }

        var cardd = new Card
        {
            Title = card.Title,
            ImageUrl = card.ImageUrl,
            Destination = card.Destination,
            Receiver = card.Receiver,
            Model = card.Model,
            UserFullName = card.UserFullName,
            SNumber = card.SNumber,
            QNumber = card.QNumber,
            PublicView = card.PublicView
        };

        this.data.Cards.Add(cardd);
        this.data.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("All","Cards");
    }

    public IActionResult All()
    {
        var cards = this.data.Cards
                             .Where(c => c.PublicView == true).ToList();

        var usern = User.Identity.Name;
       
        if(usern!=this.User.Identity.Name)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var cardsl = cards  
            .Select(c => new CardAllViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Title = c.Title,
                ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                Destination = c.Destination,
                SNumber = c.SNumber,
                QNumber = c.QNumber
            })     
            .ToList();

        return View(cardsl);
    }
   
    public IActionResult Details(string cardId)
    {
        var card = this.data.Cards.Where(c => c.Id == cardId)
            .Select(c => new CardDetailsViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,                 
                ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                Title = c.Title,
                Destination = c.Destination,
                Model = c.Model,
                SNumber = c.SNumber,
                QNumber = c.QNumber
            })
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return View(card);
    }
```

The code is crashing on my view, on every div class, Title, ImageUrl, etc. The exception is

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Error]

Comment: It means that your model is `null`. Are you sure that `card` is found in your `Cards` (you have filtered result by using `Where`)?  Just set the breakpoint at line `return View(card);` and check the value of the `card`.

Comment: I know but I don't understand why.All of my cards are stored in the database and i know i have them,their values are not null for sure

Comment: So your card is `null` (when you check in debugger)?

Comment: Yeah,i dont understand why...they are in the database..the models are fine i think

Comment: You should check the value of `this.data.Cards` and value of `cardId`. I suppose the issue is either with your data (no needed card in `this.data.Cards` or with the `cardId` param. Just check them in debugger and you'll find out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I tried mock testing your code, but that doesn't seem to be a problem.

**Test Code:**
Contrller:

```
public IActionResult Details(int cardId)
{
   cardId = 5;
   List<MyFirstModel> models = new List<MyFirstModel>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      var MyFirstModel = new MyFirstModel();
      MyFirstModel.Id = i+1;
      MyFirstModel.Name = (i+1).ToString()+"Name";
      MyFirstModel.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
      MyFirstModel.price = i + 2;
      MyFirstModel.Rating = (i + 1).ToString() + "Rating";
      models.Add(MyFirstModel);
   }
   var card = models.Where(c => c.Id == cardId)
       .Select(c => new MyFirstModel
   {
      Id = c.Id,
      Name = c.Name,
      StartTime = c.StartTime,
      price = c.price
   })
   .SingleOrDefault();

   return View(card);
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]

#### Since I don't know your database context information, I can only give you two suggestions.

*1. we can check if our database connection string is correct;*

*2. if the database connection string is correct, we can make a breakpoint on "return View(card);" to see if "card" is null, check if the value of the field exists in the database.*

Comment: I want to send you the whole logic,Where i can do it?

Comment: @DimitriTfb You don't need to send me all the code, you just tell us how to create the code with the least reproducible problem.